# javascript feature detect IE tracking protection

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, soundcloud, feature-detection

Soundcloud does not support < IE11, apparently because of IE9 + IE10's tracking protection.

Is there an easy way in javascript to feature detect that tracking protection is set?

I need to mask out all IEs with tracking protection, and I would really hate to have to rely on useragent. But the only reason I have been able to dig up, for soundcloud not to support IE9 and IE10, is the tracking protection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699483(v=vs.85).aspx

the property is:

```
document.navigator.doNotTrack
```

the property is a string that returns "1" for true and "0" for false.

Comment: Wow - that was easy! I don't know why that didn't show up when I was searching for it. Thank you (without having verified that it actually works). :-)

Comment: Also saw in another place in the docs that it it may be ".msdonottrack" just so you know